Is there a SE site for collectable cards like basketball or football?
I saw a question about comic books and I thought cards would be a good question  to ask. Being a Magic card collector I would like to know what everyone thought.

Can you provide an example of a question about collectible card games that you'd like to ask? We should then be able to determine whether there's an existing site that would accept that question.

For sports trading cards specifically, your best bet is Sports, where there are 3 questions about trading cards (see the [collectibles] tag).
If it's part of a card game, like Magic the Gathering, see Board and Card Games.
